# truffle migrate fails with Network state unknown, Error: account is locked

Tags: web3js, truffle, testrpc

I'm trying to run the truffle demo on the ethereum testnet but truffle migrate fails with "Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually. Error: account is locked"

I'm running test net using the command

```
geth --testnet --rpc --rpcapi db,eth,net,web3,personal --cache=1024  --rpcport 8545 --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --rpccorsdomain "*" --bootnodes "enode://20c9ad97c081d63397d7b685a412227a40e23c8bdc6688c6f37e97cfbc22d2b4d1db1510d8f61e6a8866ad7f0e17c02b14182d37ea7c3c8b9c2683aeb6b733a1@52.169.14.227:30303,enode://6ce05930c72abc632c58e2e4324f7c7ea478cec0ed4fa2528982cf34483094e9cbc9216e7aa349691242576d552a2a56aaeae426c5303ded677ce455ba1acd9d@13.84.180.240:30303"
```

and then in another tab:

```
truffle console
web3.personal.newAccount('samplepassword')
web3.personal.unlockAccount(account hash, 'samplepassword', 15000)
migrate
```

I've tried using both testrpc and ethereum testnet, and have gotten the same account locked error both times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried creating the new account straight from geth?.

```
geth attach
personal.newAccount(passphrase)
"0xb03c6008a4d3de476af9028167ddf285cd0bc397"
personal.unlockAccount("0xb03c6008a4d3de476af9028167ddf285cd0bc397")
```